# Problema en consulta Select de MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql, select

tengo un problema en una Query en MySQL, actualmente tengo dos tablas, una de empleados y otra de lugares que ha visitado dicho empleado por fecha, el objetivo es obtener a través de una consulta la lista de todos los empleados y el último lugar que visitaron, hasta ahí todo bien, el problema es que algunos empleados no tienen ningún movimiento y por lo tanto no logro incluirlos en mi resultado final, anexaré imágenes de mis tablas y mi consulta actual, espero me puedan apoyar. Muchas gracias.

[image: Mis dos tablas, así como mi consulta actual, en la cual no logro incluir los contactos que no tienen ningún movimiento]

La Query utilizada es el siguiente:

```
SELECT tblempleados.Id AS idEmp, 
tblempleados.Nombre AS NombreEmpleado, 
tblmovimientos.Id AS IdUltimoMov, 
tblmovimientos.Area, 
tblmovimientos.FechaMovimiento AS Fecha,
tblmovimientos.IdCargo as idCargo
FROM (bd_secjo.tblmovimientos 
inner JOIN bd_secjo.tblempleados ON tblempleados.Id=tblmovimientos.IDEmpleado)
WHERE tblmovimientos.FechaMovimiento
IN (SELECT MAX(FechaMovimiento) FROM bd_secjo.tblmovimientos GROUP BY IdEmpleado)
```

Comment: Puedes agregar un IF para validar si el campo es nulo IF(CONDICION,TRUE,FALSE) :)

Comment: Perdón no entiendo, en que parte? disculpa es que apenas empiezo en esto de las consultas

Comment: En tu Where porque en el IN traes solo los que coincidan con las fechas que estan dentro de bd_secjo.tblmovimientos, pero si el usuario no tiene no la muestra

Comment: Lo estoy intentado pero no le encuentro, sé que es mucho pedir pero crees que sea posible que me regales un ejemplo?

Comment: Creo que te puede funcionar algo asi SELECT tblempleados.Id AS idEmp, 
tblempleados.Nombre AS NombreEmpleado, 
tblmovimientos.Id AS IdUltimoMov, 
tblmovimientos.Area, 
tblmovimientos.FechaMovimiento AS Fecha,
tblmovimientos.IdCargo as idCargo
FROM (bd_secjo.tblmovimientos 
LEFT JOIN bd_secjo.tblempleados ON tblempleados.Id=tblmovimientos.IDEmpleado)
ORDER BY tblmovimientos.FechaMovimiento

Aca no uso IF mas bien LEFT y ORDER

Answer (score 1):

Primero debes hacer una subconsulta que arroje el último movimientos de los colaboradores y luego haces un left join con el resto de las tablas

```
with ultimo_mov (IdEmpleado,FechaMovimiento) AS
(SELECT IdEmpleado, MAX(FechaMovimiento) FROM bd_secjo.tblmovimientos GROUP BY IdEmpleado)
SELECT tblempleados.Id AS idEmp, 
tblempleados.Nombre AS NombreEmpleado, 
ultimo_mov.Id AS IdUltimoMov, 
ultimo_mov.Area, 
ultimo_mov.FechaMovimiento AS Fecha,
ultimo_mov.IdCargo as idCargo
FROM bd_secjo.tblempleados 
LEFT JOIN ultimo_mov ON (tblempleados.Id=ultimo_mov.IDEmpleado)

De esta manera se incluyen todos los valores de la tabla tblempleados
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes que  hacer tu select a la tabla tblempleados por que los quieres todos no?

```
SELECT tb_emp.Id AS idEmp, 
tb_emp.Nombre AS NombreEmpleado, 
from bd_secjo.tblempleados as tb_emp
```

Eso traera todos los empleados, luego hay que hacer un select dentro del anterios que nos traiga ese ultimo movimiento que necesitas

```
SELECT tb_emp.Id AS idEmp, 
 tb_emp.Nombre AS NombreEmpleado, (select tblmovimientos.Id from 
  bd_secjo.tblmovimientos  where tb_emp.id=tblmovimientos.id)
 from bd_secjo.tblempleados as tb_emp
```

Y asi un select mas dentro del primer selec para cada campo que necesitas

Comment: Ya lo intenté y si funcionó el problema es que consume demasiados recursos, tendría que hacer un select por cada columna y es una sobrecarga al servidor.

Comment: En mi servidor local pues no hay problema, tengo suficientes recursos, el problema es que la consulta arrojará casi 3 mil empleados y está alojado en un hosting por lo que debo cuidar cada consulta que haga.